# Subset sequence c#

Tags: c#, sum, duplicates, subset

I have a problem with one exercise. Task is to find all subsets within the array which have a sum equal to N and print them. Also I need to find all unique subsets and this is the problem. I am using Gray method to find all combinations but some of them are duplicated. Here's my code:

```
    int matchSum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    int combinations = (int) Math.Pow(2, numbers.Length);
    List<int> currentSequence = new List<int>();

    bool foundMatch = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < combinations; i++)
    {
        for (int bit = 0; bit < Convert.ToString(i,2).Length; bit++)
        {
            int mask = (i >> bit) & 1;
            if (mask == 1)
            {
                currentSequence.Add(numbers[numbers.Length-bit-1]);
            }
        }
        if (currentSequence.Sum() == matchSum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", string.Join(" + ", currentSequence), matchSum);
            foundMatch = true;
        }
        currentSequence.Clear();
    }

    if (!foundMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No matching subsets.");
    }
```

Best regards!

Comment: Create a list of subsets that you have already found.  A List<string> would work if you represent the sequence e.g. as a comma separated string.  Search the List<string> to see if the current subset exists.  If the number of subsets is at all large, you can use a sorted list, or a hashset (though there is a remote chance of a hash collision).

Comment: Can you provide a sample data? So we can understand your question.

Comment: Will the list contain only positive numbers?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No. Positive and negative numbers can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a backtracking algorithm implementation. It works by first sorting the input set and then producing the subsets and checking the sum. There are 3 key points. First, the algorithm maintains the current sum all the time so it doesn't need to fully calculate it at each step. Second, it early stops if the current sum becomes larger than the target sum. And finally, in order to produce unique subsets, the back step skips the numbers that are equal to the last number of the previous sequence. Hope that helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Samples
{
    class Sample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int matchSum = 20; // int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] numbers = { 5, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 8, 7, 4 }; // Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            Array.Sort(numbers);
            var stack = new Stack<int>();
            int matchCount = 0, currentSum = 0, nextPos = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                // Next
                for (int nextSum; nextPos < numbers.Length; currentSum = nextSum, nextPos++)
                {
                    nextSum = currentSum + numbers[nextPos];
                    if (nextSum > matchSum) break;
                    stack.Push(nextPos);
                    if (nextSum < matchSum) continue;
                    matchCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", matchSum, string.Join(" + ", stack.Reverse().Select(pos => numbers[pos])));
                    stack.Pop();
                    break;
                }
                // Back
                if (stack.Count == 0) break;
                var lastPos = stack.Pop();
                var lastNumber = numbers[lastPos];
                currentSum -= lastNumber;
                nextPos = lastPos + 1;
                while (nextPos < numbers.Length && numbers[nextPos] == lastNumber)
                    nextPos++;
            }
            if (matchCount == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No matching subsets.");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That was the idea. If it was said that the input set contains only positive numbers, at the beginning (after sorting) I would eliminate all the numbers at the end of the sorted set that are bigger than the target sum.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I probably haven't explained it well. The algorithm does not stop the whole process, just the "forward" step. Note that the set in sorted, so the next numbers are guaranteed to be bigger, so the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way with a HashSet (thanks @Eric J.).
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

```
class Program
{
    static List<int> currentMatchList = new List<int>();
    static void Main()
    {
        int matchSum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        int combinations = (int)Math.Pow(2, numbers.Length);
        List<int> currentSequence = new List<int>();
        HashSet<string> allResults = new HashSet<string>();

        bool foundMatch = false;

        for (int i = 1; i < combinations; i++)
        {
            for (int bit = 0; bit < Convert.ToString(i, 2).Length; bit++)
            {
                int mask = (i >> bit) & 1;
                if (mask == 1)
                {
                    currentSequence.Add(numbers[numbers.Length - bit - 1]);
                }
            }
            if (currentSequence.Sum() == matchSum)
            {
                string temp = "";
                currentSequence.OrderBy(a => a).ToList().ForEach(a => temp += a + " ");
                if (!allResults.Contains(temp))
                {
                    allResults.Add(temp);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", string.Join(" + ", currentSequence), matchSum);
                }
                foundMatch = true;
            }
            currentSequence.Clear();
        }

        if (!foundMatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No matching subsets.");
        }
    }
}
```